Why would a server not send ACK in response to PSH, ACK?
We have a client/server implementation, where the client continuously, periodically sends data at 800Hz over ethernet. The packets are small so we're significantly under the network bandwidth limit.
For most of the operation, the server responds with an ACK to every of the clients' PSH, ACK messages. However, occasionally there will be 5 consecutive PSH,ACK which receive 1 delayed ACK from the server. This bottleneck is problematic.
We've tried setting TCP_NODELAY and TCP_QUICKACK but these don't seem to fix it. The client flushes the write, and this is timed so we see this seems to happen sufficiently fast.
We can't quite see what reasons the server would have for not sending an ACK, and for delaying so much (5 message durations + additional ~3ms). Are there any options that could affect this?

"This bottleneck is problematic." - why? What in your application needs that the ACK happens immediately?

How are you validating this? It needs to be done on the server, and it seems like that hasn't been done. It sounds like it is being measured on the endpoint, and assuming that the server is not sending the ACK.

Also what is the length of "five message durations"?

Problematic because our application needs real-time data transmission. The client waits for ACKS to not fill the congestion window, which is of course solvable. But the larger problem here is the server seeming to freeze up, which prevents real-time data.
Validating with wireshark, I see this grouping visually and the lack of ACK from the server.
Transmitting at 800hz, 5 messages covers a duration of approx 6ms. Plus it tends to delay a bit more (~2-3ms) before finally sending the ACK. Note each message is small (<100 bytes)
